# Is every finite group the automorphism group of a smooth projective curve?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, finite-groups, algebraic-curves

$\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}$Let $G$ be a finite group and let $k$ be a field with algebraic closure $K$. Is there a smooth projective curve $C$ defined over $k$ such that $\Aut_k(C)=\Aut_K(C)$ is isomorphic to $G$?

If $k=\mathbb{C}$ the answer is yes and is a classical result of Greenberg,  *L.  Greenberg,  [Maximal  groups  and  signatures](https://doi.org/10.1515/9781400881642-017), Ann.  of Math.  Studies 79 (1974), 207—226.*

It was generalised to algebraic closed fields in *D. Madden, R. Valentini, [The group of automorphisms of algebraic function fields](https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1983.343.162).  J. Reine Angew. Math. 343 (1983), 162–168.*

What happens for a general field $k$? For instance for $k=\mathbb{R}$?

Is there a simple construction? Does someone have a reference?

Comment: Probably a generic complete intersection of $G$-invariant hypersurfaces of high degree in a high-dimensional representation of $G$ will do the trick.

Comment: I would wonder if pants gluing could be flexible enough to produce a construction that is defined over the reals (or even over the rationals?)

Comment: @YCor If that worked, would that produce a solution with the additional stipulation $C/G \cong \mathbb P^1$? Such a thing would give a solution to the inverse Galois problem...

Comment: @WillSawin You probably refer to the "over the rationals" part. Good point. Let's stick to reals, as one can imagine what a pair-of-pants with a Galois involution is.

Comment: Is it known for $G=\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})$? The Klein quartic is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ but if I recall correctly its automorphisms are not.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Your memory is right. Let $g$ be an element of order $7$ in $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}/7 \mathbb{Z})$ and let $X$ be the Klein quartic. Then the action of $g$ on $X$ has $3$ fixed points. If the action was defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, then these points would form a Galois orbit. So there would be a cubic extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ such that one of these fixed points $x$ is defined over $K$. But the action on the tangent space at  $x$ is by a primitive $7$-th root of unity, and cannot lie in a cubic field $K$.

Comment: This sort of argument makes it easy to rule out many concrete examples, but it seems powerless in the case that $G$ acts freely on $X$.